# A problem about $-\max$ and $\min$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, linear-programming

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are convex compact subsets in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $\langle.,.\rangle$ be the standard inner product.
Does the following equality

$$\max_{y\in Y} [\langle y, z\rangle- \max_{x\in X}\langle y, x\rangle]=\max_{y\in Y} \min_{x\in X}\langle y, z-x\rangle $$

hold?

I saw the term on the l.h.s. in elemetary convex analysis books but have never seen the term on the r.h.s. in any book. So it makes me unsure about whether this equality is true.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\langle y, z-x\rangle =\langle y,z \rangle-\langle y,x \rangle$. Hence 
$$\min_{x \in X} \langle y, z-x\rangle=\min_{x \in X}[\langle y,z \rangle-\langle y,x \rangle]=\langle y,z\rangle -\max_{x \in X}\langle y,x \rangle.$$
Now apply the $\max_{y \in Y}$ on both sides.